# Regex expression that will match everything except what's in parenthesis

Tags: regex

I have a file layout and I'd like to remove everything except the numbers inside parenthesis. An example of the layout is:

```
C10438     03  EXT-OBLN-ASSN           PIC X(05).    
           03  EXT-OWN-NAME            PIC X(40).
```

I used

```
(^[^\(]*)
```

to match everything up to the open parenthesis. However when I try

```
(^[^\(\d{2}\)]*)
```

I only get the white spaces at the start of the line and I have no idea why!

Comment: Part of the problem with your attempt was the stuff between square brackets. Those are *literal* characters for the character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to achieve that in Notepad++.

NOTE: `(^[^\(\d{2}\)]*)` contains a logical error: `\(\d{2}\)` is supposed to be a *sequence* of characters (like `(22)`), but is placed into a *negated character class* where each symbol (other than the first `^`) is treated as a separate symbol. So, `(^[^\(\d{2}\)]*)` matches and captures into a group everything that is not a `(`, a digit, `{`, `2`, `}`, `)`, zero or more times, from the beginning of the string/line.

You need a regex that will match any characters, any number of occurrences (`.*`) from the start of the line (`^`) up to the `(` followed with one or more digits (`\d+`) and then followed with `)` and any amount of any characters but a newline.

Use

```
^.*\((\d+)\).*
```

And replace with `$1`.

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD1nD9/1)

If it is not for Notepad++, make sure you pass the `/m` MULTILINE modifier so that `^` could match the beginning of a line, not the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

use this pattern

```
.*?(\(\d\d\))|.*
```

and replace w/ `$1`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO7wU7/1)

---

or to remove parenthesis as well, use this pattern

```
.*?\((\d\d)\)|.*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO7wU7/2)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
\(\p{N}+\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aH2vK5/1

This captures any parenthesis ( `\(` and `\)` ) and any number of digits in it (`\p{N}+`).

Comment: The Unicode category classes are not available in some regex flavors.